# How can I verify the algorithm used for FDE is actually AES-128?

Tags: aes, disk-encryption, hardware

I would like to check whether the algorithm that is used to encrypt my SSD drive is actually AES-128.

I wanted to read the raw disk data, encrypt them myself and then diff the data against the encrypted disk data to check if there is a difference or not. I have found the article that states:

> The Encryption Key never leaves the device and is known only by the drive itself. Not even the drive manufacturer knows the value of the Encryption Key.

http://electronicdesign.com/memory/securing-ssds-aes-disk-encryption

Since I cannot access the Encryption Key, the verification process described above cannot be performed.

How can I make sure the manufacturer of the SSD that advertises AES-128 encryption does not in fact use some other algorithm?

Comment: Since the algorithm is implemented in a closed-source, proprietary way, there usually isnt any practical way to know for sure. And even if it's AES, who sais they don't use weak keys / S-boxes / other parts. That how i would backdoor crypto, and that's probably how you would be vulnerable, intentionally or through incompetence. To avoid all this, use open source crypto on top of anything you use.

Comment: @J.A.K. What is a "weak S-box" in the context of AES?

Comment: @forest I guess it wouldn't be AES anymore if you modified it. I mean the possibility of a perverted AES-like scheme, but with with [substitution boxes that introduce weakness (p 28)](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-17/materials/eu-17-Filiol-By-Design-Backdooring-Of-Encryption-System-Can-We-Trust-Foreign-Encryption-Algorithms.pdf)